# How to parse dict in Ansible

Tags: json, dictionary, ansible

So I have a dict data like this:

```
{
  "json_response": [
    {
      "message": "The value is 1505. xxxxxxx: xxxxxx: This is a big value. xxxxx.",
      "value": "1505"
    },
    {
      "message": "The value is 5. xxxxxxx: xxxxxxx: This is a small value. xxxxx.",
      "value": "5"
    },
    {
      "message": "The value is 500. xxxxxxx: xxxxxxx: This is a medium value. xxxxx.",
      "value": "500"
    }   
  ]
}
```

I want to parse the value in message and the output that i want to achieve is something like this:

```
{
  "json_response": [
    {
      "message": "The value is 1505. This is a big value.",
      "value": "1505"
    },
    {
      "message": "The value is 5. This is a small value.",
      "value": "5"
    },
    {
      "message": "The value is 500. This is a medium value.",
      "value": "500"
    }   
  ]
}
```

What should i do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't understand exactly what you want to do, but basically you can do a lot of crazy things:

```yaml
- name: Define input json text block
  set_fact:
    input_json: |
      {
        "json_response": [
          {
            "message": "The value is 1505. xxxxxxx: xxxxxx: This is a big value. xxxxx.",
            "value": "1505"
          },
          {
            "message": "The value is 5. xxxxxxx: xxxxxxx: This is a small value. xxxxx.",
            "value": "5"
          },
          {
            "message": "The value is 500. xxxxxxx: xxxxxxx: This is a medium value. xxxxx.",
            "value": "500"
          }   
        ]
      }

- name: Parse json
  set_fact:
    parsed_json: "{{ input_json | from_json }}"

- name: Print first response
  debug:
    msg: "{{ parsed_json['json_response'] | first }}"

- name: Print first values
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ['value'] | map('extract', ( parsed_json['json_response'] | first ) ) }}"

- name: Print all values
  debug:
    msg: "{{ range(parsed_json['json_response'] | length) | map('extract', parsed_json['json_response'], ['value']) }}"

- name: Print all messages
  debug:
    msg: "{{ range(parsed_json['json_response'] | length) | map('extract', parsed_json['json_response'], ['message']) }}"

- name: Fetch all values extracted from the messages
  debug:
    msg: "{{ range(parsed_json['json_response'] | length) | map('extract', parsed_json['json_response'], ['message']) | map('regex_search', '\\d+') }}"
```

This produces the following output

```
TASK [Define input json text block] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Parse json] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print first response] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "message": "The value is 1505. xxxxxxx: xxxxxx: This is a big value. xxxxx.",
        "value": "1505"
    }
}

TASK [Print first values] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "1505"
    ]
}

TASK [Print all values] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "1505",
        "5",
        "500"
    ]
}

TASK [Print all messages] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "The value is 1505. xxxxxxx: xxxxxx: This is a big value. xxxxx.",
        "The value is 5. xxxxxxx: xxxxxxx: This is a small value. xxxxx.",
        "The value is 500. xxxxxxx: xxxxxxx: This is a medium value. xxxxx."
    ]
}

TASK [Fetch all values extracted from the messages] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "1505",
        "5",
        "500"
    ]
}
```

I hope this helps you to reach your goal.